# Can we use more than one irreducible polynomial in AES?

Tags: aes, keys, s-boxes

I understand that the irr. poly is used to form the s-box (and inv. s-box), the key schedule and the mix columns. But could we use a different irr. poly for the mix columns and another for the key schedule (using, of course, a different s-box)?

Thanks...

Comment: Yes, but then it would no longer be AES

Comment: Technically I don't see why not. You might want to construct a more specific question though; do you want to know if the result would still be secure or if this would have any benefits? Do you have an intended use case (i.e. *why* do you want to do this)?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes - Assume sender/receiver have a way to agree on how to randomly select any of the 30 irr. polys; perhaps the same one throughout, or better (is it?) use different irr. polys for different parts of the algorithm (one for the s-box, another for the key schedule, say). Would this be harder to cryptanalyse? More secure?